# Serializing Array of Binary Trees

Tags: f#, binary-tree

The following code creates an array of simple binary trees and attempts to serialize and deserialize it. However, I don't know how to convert the object created by formatter.Deserialize(fso) back to an array of trees. I just get the error "This expression was expected to have type Tree array but here has type obj."

```
type Tree = | Branch of (string*float)*(Tree*Tree)
            | Leaf of float

let trees = [|Branch (("x1", 0.), (Leaf 0., Leaf 1.)); Branch (("x2", 0.), (Leaf 0., Leaf 1.))|]

//Serialize
let filename = "C:/tree.dat"
let fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create)
let formatter = new BinaryFormatter()
formatter.Serialize(fs, trees)
fs.Close()

//Deserialize
let fso = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)
let (trees2:array<Tree>) = formatter.Deserialize(fso)
fso.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let trees2 = formatter.Deserialize(fso) :?> Tree[]
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of `formatter.Deserialize` is `obj` which doesn't match the type `array<Tree>`, and so you need a downcast:

```
...
let trees2 = formatter.Deserialize(fso) :?> array<Tree>
```

or

```
let (trees2:array<Tree>) = downcast formatter.Deserialize(fso)
```